# spyder for R language

Tags: python, r, anaconda, conda, spyder

I have created a conda environment. Through this environment I run python. After that I started using spyder. I would like to ask if there is any way to use spyder for R language.The relevant packages i have installed are:

```
conda list
# packages in environment at .../2609_385_intel:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
_libgcc_mutex             0.1                 conda_forge    conda-forge
_openmp_mutex             4.5                       2_gnu    conda-forge
_r-mutex                  1.0.1               anacondar_1    conda-forge
aiohttp                   3.8.5            py38h5eee18b_0
aiosignal                 1.3.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
alabaster                 0.7.13             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
argon2-cffi               23.1.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
argon2-cffi-bindings      21.2.0           py38h01eb140_4    conda-forge
more packages....
qtwebkit                  5.212                h3fafdc1_5
r-base                    4.2.0                h1ae530e_0
r-base64enc               0.1_3           r42h57805ef_1006    conda-forge
r-bitops                  1.0_7             r42h57805ef_2    conda-forge
r-cli                     3.6.1             r42ha503ecb_1    conda-forge
r-cpp11                   0.4.6             r42hc72bb7e_0    conda-forge
r-crayon                  1.5.2             r42hc72bb7e_2    conda-forge
r-data.table              1.14.8            r42h57805ef_1    conda-forge
r-digest                  0.6.33            r42ha503ecb_0    conda-forge
r-dplyr                   1.1.3             r42ha503ecb_0    conda-forge
r-ellipsis                0.3.2             r42h57805ef_2    conda-forge
r-evaluate                0.22              r42hc72bb7e_0    conda-forge
r-fansi                   1.0.5             r42h57805ef_0    conda-forge
r-fastmap                 1.1.1             r42ha503ecb_1    conda-forge
r-generics                0.1.3             r42hc72bb7e_2    conda-forge
r-glue                    1.6.2             r42h57805ef_2    conda-forge
r-htmltools               0.5.6.1           r42ha503ecb_0    conda-forge
r-irdisplay               1.1               r42hd8ed1ab_2    conda-forge
r-irkernel                1.3.2             r42h785f33e_1    conda-forge
r-jsonlite                1.8.7             r42h57805ef_0    conda-forge
r-lifecycle               1.0.3             r42hc72bb7e_2    conda-forge
r-lubridate               1.9.3             r42h57805ef_0    conda-forge
r-magrittr                2.0.3             r42h57805ef_2    conda-forge
r-pbdzmq                  0.3_10            r42ha81a24b_0    conda-forge
r-pillar                  1.9.0             r42hc72bb7e_1    conda-forge
r-pkgconfig               2.0.3             r42hc72bb7e_3    conda-forge
r-r6                      2.5.1             r42hc72bb7e_2    conda-forge
r-rcurl                   1.98_1.12         r42h133d619_0    conda-forge
r-repr                    1.1.6             r42h785f33e_1    conda-forge
r-rlang                   1.1.1             r42ha503ecb_1    conda-forge
r-tibble                  3.2.1             r42h57805ef_2    conda-forge
r-tidyselect              1.2.0             r42hc72bb7e_1    conda-forge
r-timechange              0.2.0             r42ha503ecb_1    conda-forge
r-utf8                    1.2.3             r42h57805ef_1    conda-forge
r-uuid                    1.1_1             r42h57805ef_0    conda-forge
r-vctrs                   0.6.4             r42ha503ecb_0    conda-forge
r-withr                   2.5.1             r42hc72bb7e_0    conda-forge
readline                  8.2                  h5eee18b_0
requests                  2.31.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
rich                      13.5.3             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
more packages...
```

Comment: As far as I know, you can't use Spyder for R, but you can go the other way and use Posit (a.k.a Rstudio) for both R and Python...

Comment: Rstudio is very similar to spyder, and works beautifully with R

Comment: @PaulStaffordAllen Just RStudio. “Posit” is only the name of the company, not the IDE.

Comment: Ah, I thought they were migrating the whole shebang to the new name to avoid the appearance of being locked into R.  Thanks for the correction.